# If user age is greater than 18 than email id field should required and form should be disable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

Currently I am using this code.
When user select the date of birth in datepicker this function calculates it and disabled the save button if it is greater than 18.
The Problem is when I select the age below 18 then the validation on fields below the email id is not taken into consideration and form get submitted.

Compnent.ts code:

```
checkAge(event) {
    var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("submit");
    //get date of birth of family members
    this.userFamilyForm.get('dob').valueChanges.subscribe((dob: any) => {
      let todayDate = new Date();
      var dobDate = new Date(dob);
       this.years = Math.floor((todayDate.getTime() - dobDate.getTime()) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      if (this.years >= 18) {
        element.disabled = true;
        this.userFamilyForm.get('email').setValidators(Validators.compose([CustomValidators.required, CustomValidators.checkEmail]));
      }
      else {
        element.disabled = false;
        this.userFamilyForm.get('email').setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
      }
    });
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<div class="col-md-5 no-pd">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dob" class="required">
            {{'userFamily.labels.DATE_OF_BIRTH' | translate}}
        </label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'userFamily.placeholder.DATE_OF_BIRTH' | translate}}" bsDatepicker
                #drp="bsDatepicker" formControlName="dob" [maxDate]="maxDate" (ngModelChange)="checkAge($event)" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="drp.toggle()">
                    <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="userFamilyForm.controls['dob'].hasError('required') && userFamilyForm.controls['dob'].hasError('required') && (userFamilyForm.controls['dob'].touched || userFamilyForm.controls['dob'].touched)">
                {{'userFamily.errors.DOB_PHN_REQUIRED' | translate}}
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="required">
            {{'userFamily.labels.EMAIL' | translate}}
        </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" id="email">
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="userFamilyForm.controls['email']?.errors?.checkRequired && userFamilyForm.controls['email'].touched">{{'userFamily.errors.EMAIL_ERROR_VALID' | translate}}</span>
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="!userFamilyForm.controls['email']?.errors?.checkRequired && userFamilyForm.controls['email']?.errors?.checkEmail  && (userFamilyForm.controls['email'].dirty || userFamilyForm.controls['email'].touched)">{{'userFamily.errors.EMAIL_ERROR' | translate}}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your html form?

Comment: I have added HTML form please check